# Deployed NextJS app to Vercel failed Deployment only says "Failed to Compile"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I can't figure out why my deployment is crashing because i'm not getting any significant error messages, just loads of warnings that it should still run on (its ran in the past with these same warnings)

Here is the build log:

```
Running build in Cleveland, USA (East) – cle1
Cloning github.com/shaunsmerling/ecomjobs (Branch: main, Commit: 8953abf)
Cloning completed: 2.582s
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 28.15.7
Installing dependencies...
> ecomjobs@0.1.0 postinstall
> prisma generate || true
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
✔ Generated Prisma Client (4.10.1 | library) to ./node_modules/@prisma/client in 124ms
You can now start using Prisma Client in your code. Reference: https://pris.ly/d/client
```

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

```
added 284 packages, removed 49 packages, and changed 199 packages in 15s
224 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
Detected Next.js version: 13.1.6
Running "npm run build:prod"
> ecomjobs@0.1.0 build:prod
> npm run prisma:update && npm run build
> ecomjobs@0.1.0 prisma:update
> npx prisma db push
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MongoDB database "ejserver" at "ejserver0.krz3l.mongodb.net"
The database is already in sync with the Prisma schema.
Running generate... (Use --skip-generate to skip the generators)
Running generate... - Prisma Client
✔ Generated Prisma Client (4.10.1 | library) to ./node_modules/@prisma/client in
 122ms
> ecomjobs@0.1.0 build
> next build
info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
warn  - The Next.js plugin was not detected in your ESLint configuration. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#migrating-existing-config
Failed to compile.
./pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js
31:21  Warning: 'res' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
./pages/api/company.js
49:5  Warning: Expected a default case.  default-case
./pages/api/emails.js
48:7  Warning: Expected a default case.  default-case
./pages/api/jobs.js
58:5  Warning: Expected a default case.  default-case
./pages/api/register.js
51:5  Error: 'accpassword' is not defined.  no-undef
55:20  Error: 'email' is not defined.  no-undef
59:48  Error: 'email' is not defined.  no-undef
70:5  Warning: Expected a default case.  default-case
./pages/api/users.js
4:5  Warning: 'getUserById' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
51:7  Warning: Expected a default case.  default-case
./pages/australian-jobs.js
12:8  Warning: 'Filter' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
20:23  Warning: 'setClearFilter' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
25:17  Warning: 'session' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
28:27  Warning: Invalid typeof comparison value.  valid-typeof
60:9  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/blog/build-a-brand-on-shopify.js
37:17  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
60:19  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
74:15  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
98:17  Warning: Using target="_blank" without rel="noreferrer" (which implies rel="noopener") is a security risk in older browsers: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/#recommendations  react/jsx-no-target-blank
114:17  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/blog/five-proven-methods-to-increase-your-shopify-brands-aov-in-2023.js
37:17  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
60:19  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
74:15  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
98:17  Warning: Using target="_blank" without rel="noreferrer" (which implies rel="noopener") is a security risk in older browsers: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/#recommendations  react/jsx-no-target-blank
114:17  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/blog/index.js
3:10  Warning: 'useState' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
3:20  Warning: 'useEffect' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
70:11  Warning: The href attribute is required for an anchor to be keyboard accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide an href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
119:13  Warning: The href attribute is required for an anchor to be keyboard accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide an href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
168:13  Warning: The href attribute is required for an anchor to be keyboard accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide an href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
216:13  Warning: The href attribute is required for an anchor to be keyboard accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide an href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/blog/top-7-ecommerce-trends-in-2023.js
37:17  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
60:19  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
74:15  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
99:17  Warning: Using target="_blank" without rel="noreferrer" (which implies rel="noopener") is a security risk in older browsers: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/#recommendations  react/jsx-no-target-blank
115:17  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/blog/what-is-google-shopping.js
1:17  Warning: 'useState' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
43:17  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
66:19  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
80:15  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
104:17  Warning: Using target="_blank" without rel="noreferrer" (which implies rel="noopener") is a security risk in older browsers: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/#recommendations  react/jsx-no-target-blank
121:17  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/brands/index.js
1:16  Warning: 'useState' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
1:26  Warning: 'useEffect' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
./pages/business-operations-jobs.js
12:8  Warning: 'Filter' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
20:23  Warning: 'setClearFilter' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
25:17  Warning: 'session' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
27:9  Warning: 'bizOps' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
27:24  Warning: Unexpected string concatenation of literals.  no-useless-concat
27:30  Warning: Unexpected string concatenation of literals.  no-useless-concat
30:27  Warning: Invalid typeof comparison value.  valid-typeof
62:9  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/canada-jobs.js
12:8  Warning: 'Filter' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
20:23  Warning: 'setClearFilter' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
25:17  Warning: 'session' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
28:27  Warning: Invalid typeof comparison value.  valid-typeof
60:9  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/company/[companyId]/index.js
1:10  Warning: 'useEffect' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
1:21  Warning: 'useState' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
2:10  Warning: 'useRouter' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
129:23  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
196:19  Warning: Using target="_blank" without rel="noreferrer" (which implies rel="noopener") is a security risk in older browsers: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/#recommendations  react/jsx-no-target-blank
198:17  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
./pages/contactus.js
10:8  Warning: 'submitted' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
./pages/createaccount.js
49:25  Error: 'session' is not defined.  no-undef
157:61  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
157:169  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/creative-jobs.js
12:8  Warning: 'Filter' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
20:23  Warning: 'setClearFilter' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
25:17  Warning: 'session' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
28:27  Warning: Invalid typeof comparison value.  valid-typeof
60:9  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/customer-service-jobs.js
12:8  Warning: 'Filter' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
21:23  Warning: 'setClearFilter' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
26:17  Warning: 'session' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
29:27  Warning: Invalid typeof comparison value.  valid-typeof
64:9  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/employers/companyprofile.js
119:25  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
383:23  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
./pages/employers/posts.js
69:24  Warning: The href attribute is required for an anchor to be keyboard accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide an href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/finance-jobs.js
12:8  Warning: 'Filter' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
21:23  Warning: 'setClearFilter' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
26:17  Warning: 'session' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
29:27  Warning: Invalid typeof comparison value.  valid-typeof
64:9  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/human-resources-jobs.js
12:8  Warning: 'Filter' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
21:23  Warning: 'setClearFilter' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
26:17  Warning: 'session' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
29:27  Warning: Invalid typeof comparison value.  valid-typeof
64:9  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/index.js
2:8  Warning: 'HeroBanner' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
12:8  Warning: 'LogoBanner' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
19:8  Warning: 'Grid' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
28:17  Warning: 'session' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
31:27  Warning: Invalid typeof comparison value.  valid-typeof
./pages/job/[jobId]/index.js
1:10  Warning: 'useEffect' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
1:21  Warning: 'useState' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
4:8  Warning: 'Footer' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
139:17  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
141:96  Warning: Unexpected string concatenation of literals.  no-useless-concat
142:17  Warning: Using target="_blank" without rel="noreferrer" (which implies rel="noopener") is a security risk in older browsers: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/#recommendations  react/jsx-no-target-blank
./pages/list-your-company.js
92:5  Warning: 'logo' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
211:23  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
./pages/marketing-jobs.js
12:8  Warning: 'Filter' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
20:23  Warning: 'setClearFilter' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
25:17  Warning: 'session' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
28:27  Warning: Invalid typeof comparison value.  valid-typeof
60:9  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/netherlands-jobs.js
12:8  Warning: 'Filter' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
20:23  Warning: 'setClearFilter' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
25:17  Warning: 'session' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
28:27  Warning: Invalid typeof comparison value.  valid-typeof
60:9  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/people-jobs.js
12:8  Warning: 'Filter' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
21:23  Warning: 'setClearFilter' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
26:17  Warning: 'session' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
29:27  Warning: Invalid typeof comparison value.  valid-typeof
64:9  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./pages/post/[slug].js
40:17  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
63:19  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
77:15  Warning: The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
Error: Command "npm run build:prod" exited with 1
```

Comment: can you try running a `eslint` with `--quiet` to fix all linting errors in the code first? It might have led to crashes during the build.

Command: `npm run lint -- --quiet` (guessing `lint` command is declared as `next lint`).

Comment: Hey, this did the trick. Or it let me see what errors to fixed and once fixed, it deployed. THank you so much

Answer (score 0):

if you look closely, there are actual errors buried in there

Failed to compile.
51:5  Error: 'accpassword' is not defined.  no-undef
55:20  Error: 'email' is not defined.  no-undef
59:48  Error: 'email' is not defined.  no-undef

Answer (score 0):

Check 51, 55 and 59 lines in ./pages/api/register.js

There are some errors.